# Weak convergence in Sobolev space $W_0^{1, 2}(\Omega):$ how it works?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and let $J:W_0^{1, 2}(\Omega)\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $\mathcal{C}^1$ functional. Let $(u_n)_n$ be a sequence such that
$$ u_n\to u \mbox{ in } L^2(\Omega), \quad u_n\rightharpoonup u \mbox{ in } \ W_0^{1, 2}(\Omega)\quad\mbox{ and }\quad J^{\prime}(u_n)\to 0 \mbox{ in } W^{-1, 2}(\Omega).$$

My question is: under these hypotheses, it is true that
$$J^{\prime}(u_n)(u_n -u)\to 0\quad\mbox{ and }\quad J^{\prime}(u)(u_n -u)\to 0?$$

If yes, could anyone please explain me why?

I guess it follows from the assumptions that $J^{\prime}(u_n)\to 0 \mbox{ in } W^{-1, 2}(\Omega)$ and $u_n\rightharpoonup u \mbox{ in } \ W_0^{1, 2}(\Omega)$, but I don't know how to use these informations.

Could anyone please help? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If $x_n\to x$ in $X$ and $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ in $X^*$ then $f_n(x_n)\to f(x)$. To prove this, use
$$
f_n(x_n)- f(x) = f_n(x_n-x) + (f_n-f)(x)
$$

Comment: Sorry, could you give me some more details?

Comment: you need to prove that the two summands converge both to zero. Use boundedness and the convergence assumptions.

Comment: I am interested in that notation ⇀. What does it stand for?

Comment: weak convergence